# How to create a list of object by using some sort of filter with a predicate

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm iterating through a list of nodes in order to create edges between them, however I want to check if the edge between two nodes are not crossing a 'dangerous' place, so I created a function that will work as a predicate to insure I do not create a such an edge. However I don't see how I would be able to properly build my list of edges.

The types manipulated are :

```
type position = float * float
type node = position
type edge = position * position * float
```

I have written this, it doesn't work, but this is what I had in mind, I don't know what I could use in OCaml to make it work

```
let create_edges nodes_list =
  let rec create_edges_aux nodes =
    match nodes with
      | [] -> []
      | x::[] -> (x,x,0.) :: []
      | x::tl -> List.map (fun x2 -> if (is_safe_edge x x2) then (x,x2,extract_float(dist2 x x2))) tl @ create_edges_aux tl
    in create_edges_aux nodes_list
```

The problem is here obviously `List.map (fun x2 -> if (is_safe_edge x x2) then (x,x2,extract_float(dist2 x x2))) tl @ create_edges_aux tl`

The function works perfectly if I do this : `List.map (fun x2 -> (x, x2, (extract_float (dist2 x x2)))) tl @ create_edges_aux tl` but the unsafe edges aren't filtered ...

In the end my problem is that I'm not able to create a list of edges that satisfy the predicate function I coded and the goal is to be able to make that list.

If you have any ideas or solution, thanks.

Comment: If the problem is so obvious it should be easy for you to explain, shouldn't it?

Comment: @glennsl Well, I don't know what I could provide more, I'm not able to create a list of edges that satisfy the predicate, I'm trying to know if there's a function already existing in OCaml or any other way to do that

Comment: How about providing the actual error message? Or do you not consider that relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is filtering of the values, which cannot be done with `List.map` as it always take all the values.
One first option is to first filter the edges with `List.filter` then map.
If you use OCaml 4.08 or later you can use the dedicated `List.filter_map` function.
If you are using an older version of OCaml you can also use `List.fold_left` function to do the mapping and filtering.

In short, `List.map` can only modify *all* the values, if you need to filter out some values, it's not the function you need.

Comment: I ran ocaml -version, I have 4.08.1, yet when I try to use List.filter_map in Utop, it doesn't show up. Although https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html states that the function was introduced with OCaml 4.08, weird. But I'll try List.filter then List.map

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you just need an `else` part in your `if`.

A code pattern that you see a lot in OCaml is something like this:

```
let f x =
    let x' = if x > 100 then 100 else x in
    g x'
```

When using an `if` in a functional context, the `if` always needs an `else`, because the expression must have a value in both cases. Quite often the `else` value is the original (unmodified) input value.

Comment: I added the else at some point and did something like this : ```| x::tl -> List.map (fun x2 -> if (is_safe_edge x x2) then (x,x2,extract_float(dist2 x x2)) else []) tl @ create_edges_aux tl``` but I had this error : ```Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type position * position * float``` I didn't see a way of resolving this error

Comment: The `then` and `else` parts have to be the same type. Most likely you want something like `else create_edges_aux tl`.

Comment: The `else` clause has always a value but it defaults to `()` which is often not what we want

Comment: @JeffreyScofield If I do this ```| x::tl -> List.map (fun x2 -> if (is_safe_edge x x2) then (x,x2,extract_float(dist2 x x2)) else create_edges_aux tl) tl```, I have a type error : ```Error: This expression has type (position * position * float) list but an expression was expected of type position * position * float``` I think I'll opt for another way to do that, List.map seems like it won't work for my need

Comment: You're right, you can't filter a list using `List.map`. It always produces a list exactly as long as its input. I was missing the big picture, sorry.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Not a problem Jeffrey, you saved my day many times. Always appreciate seeing you answering to my stupid questions haha ! Thanks a lot.